# Limiting current to a LiPo battery

Tags: 12v, lipo, linear-regulator

(Updated: Amended text. The smaller battery is a lower voltage than I originally thought.)

I have a small 7.5V LiPo battery that needs a top-up charge of max (say) 500mA from a large 12V LiPo battery. How do I limit the current, so I do not overheat the small battery?

I am looking for the simplest and lightest option, like a simple resistor in the circuit (but I can envisage voltage problems with that).

I did see a small DC converter that said 12V to 9V converted and limited to 0.8 amps. Would that do the job?

Thanks.

(Sorry about originally mis-reading the voltage.  The supplied charger to the small LiPo battery is 12V, so I assumed that was the voltage of the battery.  But it is not - it is a 7.5V battery.)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might want to edit it to keep it technical.

Comment: Unfortunately the words simple and charge a LiPo battery do not go together. Trickle charging a LiPo is not a good idea.

Comment: DO NOT attempt to trickle-charge a lithium battery. It _will_ catch fire, explode, or do other similarly bad things.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.   I probably used the wrong terminology (trickle charge).  What I was describing is when we might attach a charger to a LiPo, and leave it on for the whole day.    Well this is similar, except the top-up charge comes from a larger LiPo.

Comment: On further investigation the smaller LiPo (in a handheld radio) is actually 7.5v (although its supplied mains charger is 12v).  So there is a voltage difference between the large 12v and small 7.5v LiPos.   I found a simple DC ‘buck converter’ on line, which is limited to 0.8 amp.   Would that be a better option than a resistor?   ...   ...   The converter says it has a controlled limiter, that will not allow more than 0.8 amp at 9v.   It seems very similar to the (12v input 9v output) DC car charger that comes with the radio - I would have used this charger, if it had the correct connectors.

Comment: @rojellis - It sounds like a good idea if the capacity of the small battery pack is 800mAh or greater (1C). However 9V is a little too high. If it’s a 7.5V battery pack, it has two cells in series. At 4.2V/cell, you need an 8.4V regulator. The resistor cannot be used with two battery packs with different number of cells (12V/3 cells; 7.5V/2 cells) - you may have serious trouble with the smaller voltage battery.

Comment: The small battery is 1,900 Ah at 7.5v.     You think a 9v charge voltage too high??   But the mains charger that comes with the battery is 12v  (from a large airband tranceiver maker).  Surely they would not supply a charger that could damage the battery...

Answer (score 1):

> . I have a small 12v LiPo battery that needs a trickle charge of max (say) 300ma from a large 12v LiPo battery. How do I limit the current, so I do not overheat the small battery (and without lowering the voltage)?

Sorry, overheating the small battery is the least of your problems. If you trickle charge a LiPo, you destroy it. Period. Don't trickle charge it.

The simplest route is to use a charge control IC.

Comment: The OP is NOT suggesting trickle charging a LiPo. Trickle charging is forcing current into a fully charged battery. That condition will never occur in the posed question.

Comment: @JackCreasey sorry, I must have been confused by the words 'trickle charge' in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a small LiPo battery be charged from a large LiPo battery. How do I limit the current, so I do not overheat the small battery (and without lowering the voltage)?

I would not describe your question as how to trickle charge a small LiPo. As pointed out in the other answer, you should NOT trickle charge LiPo's. Trickle charging is when you apply a low current over an extended period into a FULLY charged battery ….you do not seem to be suggesting that.

However, there are problems with what you are suggesting, which is to place a discharged LiPo in parallel with (I assume) a fully charged LiPo of the same voltage configuration. In this case you seem to be describing a 3S configuration for both batteries.

You have not given the specs for either battery. But let's assume as an example that you have a very large capacity (1C=10A) LiPo fully charged to 12.5V and a smaller (1C=1A) battery discharged to 10.8V.
If you connect these two batteries in parallel there will be a large current flow limited mainly by the internal resistance of the discharged battery. The current may well exceed the 1C charge capabilities of the small battery.

Since you know the maximum voltage difference between the tow batteries, a simple series resistor could limit the maximum current. In the example given a 2 Ohm resistor would ensure the peak current will never exceed 1A (12.5 - 10.8V).

In the example above the current would ramp down from a 1A maximum to zero when the two batteries reach the same terminal voltage. Even though the current reduces to a small value this IS **NOT** trickle charging. The large capacity battery is being discharged and the discharged battery re-charged. The final terminal voltage of BOTH batteries will be some point defined by their relative capacities and the current will be zero.

Comment: Simply using a resistor is probably the simplest solution, but not the one that provides the fastest charging. I would be more conservative in picking the resistor value. Assuming the big battery is fully charged and the small one is fully discharged, you should still limit the current to a safe level, let’s say 0.3A. Then you should make R>42Ω (12.5V/0.3A). The problem with this approach is that the current drops as the small battery gets charged, what leads to a long charging time. A more sophisticated approach would be to use a low-dropout active current limiter instead.

Comment: @joribama Why on earth would you limit the current to less than 1C worst case for the battery? It makes no sense.  Of course the current drops and the charge time is longer, but to do this properly (fast charge) you'd have to boost the large battery voltage which increases the complexity. At least the OP has a choice.

Comment: See my longer comment above - I discovered the large battery is 12v and the small one 7.5v.  So would a small buck converter do the trick  -  even if I left it connected all day?  (The small battery comes with a similar 12v charger, from a car cigarette lighter socket).

Comment: @JackCreasey - for safety.

Comment: @rojellis - if the voltage ratings of the two batteries are different, DON’T CONNECT THEM THROUGH A RESISTOR! You need something to limit the voltage applied to the lower voltage battery.

Comment: @joribama …..what a comment ….and I though the resitor provided that function. Exactly HOW does a resistor NOT limit the voltage the discharged battery is exposed to??? The OP already said the batteries were the same terminal voltage (3S). If the OP (in a comment) changes the battery terminal voltage of either battery then all bets are off.

Comment: @rojellis If you are changing the terminal voltage of the batteries, don't do it in comments, go back and edit your question. If you want to use a large 3S and connect a smaller 2S battery you have completely different conditions.

Comment: @JackCreasey - We are both saying the same thing, just with different assumptions. I’m not suggesting going below 1C. I actually agree with you (reason why I voted +1 to your answer). I’m just worried if he uses the same 2Ω resistor when the small battery is actually fully discharged (when the voltage delta will be 12.5V and the current will go way beyond 1C). In any case, it seems like he has a 3-cell pack with a 2-cell pack, in which case the resistor idea is a big NO NO. I’ll try to be more clear next time.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.  I have changed the initial question to reflect the discovery of the lower voltage on the small battery.    So I can see the balance of opinion is that a small DC buck converter is the best option.   I have purchased a small 12v to 9v converter, that says it is limited (by an IC circuit) to 800ma. I presume 9v is ok, because the manufacturer of the small battery supplied a 12v mains charger.  And 800ma should be ok too.